# get values from multiple inputs with same key django

Tags: django, request, key

I'm fighting against the django forms. When I've solved one problem a new one appears, well I got a "dynamic" html with 3 types of forms.

```
class NameForm(forms.Form):
text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'field1'}))
select =  forms.ChoiceField(widget = forms.Select(attrs={'id': 'field1'}), choices = ([('default','Select option')]), initial='default')
date = forms.DateField(widget=DateTypeInput(attrs={'id': 'field1'}))
```

And via JavaScript I create one type or other:

```
    var createElement={
    'text': '{{ form.text }}',
    'select':'{{ form.select }}',
    'date': '{{ form.date }}',  
}
```

Then I want to get all type of elements created but the problem is there are multiple inputs with name "text" or select or date.
I parse this data with method GET and this one uses a dictionary. This dict only can have one key "text".

How can I solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `request.GET.getlist('text')` to get multiple values as a list.

But you are probably better off using formsets for something like this.

Comment: great! saved me!